# Nonce question please

Tags: dapps

can I have the meaning of the word Nonce  explained please
the question is rejected .. you people really do not wish there to be normal understanding by normal every day members of the public

Comment: Hi Allan - please see the question and associated answers in the link above. If that doesn't help, please explain why, and what specific details you're looking for in an answer.